# When to use gamma vs. chi squared?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing

I took a stats test the other day and the question had a table and stated, "which statistic would be best for the table, gamma or chi squared"

Let me be real, I don't care about stats. I'm never going to take this again. I just want to be able to understand this really quick. I just need a concise "x is for this and y is for that." I've tried looking this up, and nothing comes up. Is this a nonsensical question? Because it was multiple choice so it had an answer...

I appreciate all help, thanks.

Comment: Chi-squared distributions are a sub-family of gamma distributions. In particular $\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu) \equiv \mathsf{Gamma}(\mathrm{shape} =\nu/2,\mathrm{rate} =1/2).$ So a better question would be whether the full gamma family is needed for the table, or whether the chi-squared sub-family will suffice. // Because it takes less room, many statistics books have chi-squared tables only.

Comment: so, is there an instance where one is better used over the other? or maybe i misunderstood what the question asked? Thanks!

Comment: If you're trying to get a confidence interval for the population variance $\sigma^2$ from a normal sample, then $\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(\nu = n-1),$ so chi-squared table would suffice. There are other more-general problems where information is needed about non-chisq distributions that are gamma.// If you could give specifics about the context of the discussion where this issue arises, it would be helpful.// Nowadays most of us have access to statistical computer programs that give all sorts of distributional info, so tables in books may be on the verge of obsolescence.

Comment: When you say the question had a table do you mean a table of data or a table of the function as @BruceET suggests?

Comment: @mdewey. Good question about table.